# Templated visitor that hides overloaded virtual function : SFINAE on using?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am writing a visitor templated (depending on the types we want to visit) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class INode;
class INodeVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(INode&) = 0;
    virtual ~INodeVisitor() = default;
};

template<typename ...Ts>
class TypedNodeVisitor;

template<typename T1, typename ...Ts>
class TypedNodeVisitor<T1, Ts...> : public TypedNodeVisitor<Ts...> {
public:
    virtual void visit(INode &v) override {
        if(auto p = dynamic_cast<T1*>(std::addressof(v))) {
            apply(*p);
        }

        if constexpr(sizeof...(Ts) != 0) {
            TypedNodeVisitor<Ts...>::visit(v);
        }
    }

    //using TypedNodeVisitor<Ts...>::apply;

    virtual void apply(T1 &) = 0;
};

template<>
class TypedNodeVisitor<> : public INodeVisitor {};

class INode {
public:
    void accept(INodeVisitor &nv) {
        nv.visit(*this);
    }

    virtual ~INode() = default;
};

class NodeB : public INode {};
class NodeA : public INode {};

class DrawerVisitor : public TypedNodeVisitor<NodeA, NodeB> {
public:
    void apply(NodeA &) override {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }

    void apply(NodeB &) override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto nodeA = std::make_shared<NodeA>();
    auto nodeB = std::make_shared<NodeB>();
    DrawerVisitor visitor;
    nodeA->accept(visitor);
    nodeB->accept(visitor);

    return 0;
}
```

With clang I get these warnings :

```
    prog.cc:49:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'TypedNodeVisitor<NodeA, NodeB>' requested here
class DrawerVisitor : public TypedNodeVisitor<NodeA, NodeB> {
                             ^
prog.cc:31:18: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'TypedNodeVisitor<NodeB>::apply' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('NodeB &' vs 'NodeA &')
    virtual void apply(T1 &) = 0;
```

I do understand what the issue can be, but I am not able to fix it without to add a faked definition of `apply()`  in the empty specialization of `TypedNodeVisitor<>`.

Is there a way to use `std::enable_if` on the `using TypedNodeVisitor<Ts...>::apply` ?

Comment: You need to supply a [mcve].

Comment: It works for me as long as I implement the virtual method. https://ideone.com/a8U9HG

Comment: I would split the interface apply from the implementation of visit.  Is theemre a reason you want to do both in one spot?

Comment: @super I edited my post. vdavid you use only one node, maybe it is why you do not have warnings. Yakk I did not understand what your advice is. You mean to do one interface Applyable and one interface Visitor? It will not be easy since you can add a lot of different types :)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Okay I think I understand what you meant. I need to do both at one time, but I think it is because i have some design issues, so I am working on it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use enable_if on the using `TypedNodeVisitor<Ts...>::apply` ?

As far I know, you can't: you can't templatize that type of `using` so you can use SFINAE to enable/disable it.

I don't see nothing wrong defining a "faked definition of apply in the empty specialization of `TypedNodeVisitor<>`" (IMHO it's a simple and elegant solution) but... if you really want avoid it, you can define a `TypedNodeVisitor<T0>` specialization, instead of `TypedNodeVisitor<>`, as follows

```
template <typename T0>
class TypedNodeVisitor<T0> : public INodeVisitor
 {
   public: 
    virtual void visit(INode &v) override {
        if(auto p = dynamic_cast<T0*>(std::addressof(v))) {
            apply(*p);
        }
    }

    virtual void apply(T0 &) = 0;
 };
```

This way you can also avoid the `if constexpr` test in `visit()` member (but you can avoid it also adding a fake `visit()` in `TypedNodeVisitor<>`)

Comment: Okay, I thought it was a bad idea to write a faked definition of apply. 
Btw your solution makes mandatory to write this code for both the Ts... and the T0.  So I think I will go to my first idea :)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier -  "I think I will go to my first idea" The best solution, IMHO; I suggest also a fake `virtual void visit (INode &) {}` in `TypedNodeVisitor<>` to avoid that `if constexpr` (but only for aesthetically improvement).

Comment: The if constexpr avoid a call to an empty function that is virtual. But, it is true that the compiler must optimized it ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class...Ts>
struct IApply{};
template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>
struct IApply<T0,T1,Ts...>:
  IApply<T0>,IApply<T1,Ts...>
{
  using IApply<T0>::apply;
  using IApply<T1,Ts...>::apply;
};
template<class T0>
struct IApply<T0>{
  virtual void apply(T0&)=0;
};
```

Next do this:

```
template<class Base, typename ...Ts>
class TypedNodeVisitor:public Base{};// 0 case

template<class Base, typename T1, typename ...Ts>
class TypedNodeVisitor<Base, T1, Ts...>: public TypedNodeVisitor<Base, Ts...> {
```

now we can customize our base.

```
template<class...Ts>
struct IBase: INodeVisitor, IApply<Ts...>{};

template<class...Ts>
struct ITypeNodeVisitor:TyoedNodeVisitor<IBase<Ts...>,Ts...>{};

class DrawerVisitor : public ITypedNodeVisitor<NodeA, NodeB> {
```

and done.

Also delete apply from TypedNodeVisitor.